# Galaxy SIII is displaying small-size low-quality pictures for contacts

Tags: contacts, samsung-galaxy-s-3, contact-photo

My brother and I have a Galaxy SIII, we both have the most recent firmware and software updates.

We both have the same contact whose picture is fetched from his Facebook profile picture.

Whenever that contacts call either of us, her picture is naturally displayed. Only the difference is that it displays a nice, fullscreen, high resolution image for him, and a tiny, about 100x100 low-res picture for me.

What can cause this? Same contact, same picture! Is this some sort of setting I need to check?

Comment: I have often used a desktop to sign into Gmail/Contacts and update a contact image. This is then seen after a short delay in the phone, and SOMETIMES the larger version is seen soon after. Seems quite random if the larger version appears or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google contacts supports max. resolution of 98x98 apparently. 
Hope they will fix this soon.
Anyway if you set high res. photos in the phone they will be displayed accordingly until you restore again your contacts from google servers.

Answer (score 1):

I confirm that setting the photo using the phone fixes the resolution, at least in some places (my starred list seems to insist on low resolution). Surprisingly, it turns out that if we add the contact to the Starred in Android group from contacts app in desktop, and then set the high-resolution photo, when this change gets synced with the phone the resolution gets fixed as well.